# Searching on date ranges with Lucene in Java?

Tags: java, lucene, date

Is it possible to search on date ranges using Lucene in Java? How do I build Lucene search queries based on date fields and dates ranges? For example:

- between specified dates
- prior to a specified date
- after a specified date
- within the last 24 hours
- within the past week
- within the past month.

[Edit] i'm using Lucene 2.4.1 and my system is really legacy and really poorly tested so i would like if possible not to have to upgrade

Comment: Yes it is possible. If you need some sample code I'll find some for you - just ask in comment to this post. Have a look at Lucene in Action - you can find answer to this question and many others also.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Lucene (before version 2.9 anyway) only stores String values, and it only supports lexicographical range queries on that data. So if you want to store date/time data and performa range queries on it, you need to explicitly format your data/time values in such a way as to make them lexicographically ordered.

For example, store your date/times as something like `2009-10-29T15:34:00`, and then do range queries like `[2009-10-29T15:00:00 TO 2009-10-29T16:00:00]`

As has been pointed out elsewhere, Lucene 2.9 finally introduced support for range queries against non-string data, making this all rather easier.

Comment: Using `DateTools.dateToString(date, Resolution.SECOND)` method can help you to produce date string in lucene form, which is like `20110223220000`, meaning `2011-02-23 22:00:00`.