# What is wrong with this Lucene query?

Tags: java, json, servlets, lucene

What is wrong with my Lucene query? I can't understand why this is going wrong.

[27/08/12 10:28:38:447 CEST] ERROR lucene.LuceneUtils: Error ocurred trying to search results in the current index.
org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Cannot parse '+structurename:bijzonderedagen +(conhost:64d17170-c24b-4812-a788-78283d989a64 conhost:system_host) +bijzonderedagen.vestigingnaam:*Amsterdam* +bijzonderedagen.iskoopzondag:*ja* +languageid:3 +deleted:false +working:true date1:[01/01/2003 TO 01/01/2012] +working:true +((permissions:p654b0931-1027-41f7-ad4d-173115ed8ec1.1p*) )': Encountered "  "01/01/2012 "" at line 1, column 245.
Was expecting:
    "]" ...

```
at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:187)
at com.dotmarketing.util.lucene.LuceneUtils.prepareQuery(LuceneUtils.java:1195)
at com.dotmarketing.util.lucene.LuceneUtils.searchInCurrentIndex(LuceneUtils.java:507)
at com.dotmarketing.portlets.contentlet.business.ContentletFactoryDBImpl.indexSearch(ContentletFactoryDBImpl.java:388)
at com.dotmarketing.portlets.contentlet.business.ContentletAPIImpl.searchIndex(ContentletAPIImpl.java:548)
at com.dotmarketing.portlets.contentlet.business.ContentletAPIImpl.search(ContentletAPIImpl.java:453)
at com.dotmarketing.portlets.contentlet.business.ContentletAPIImpl.search(ContentletAPIImpl.java:445)
at com.dotmarketing.portlets.contentlet.business.ContentletAPIInterceptor.search(ContentletAPIInterceptor.java:1491)
at com.dotmarketing.servlets.JSONContentServlet.service(JSONContentServlet.java:172)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.dotmarketing.filters.CMSFilter.doFilter(CMSFilter.java:484)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.dotmarketing.filters.AutoLoginFilter.doFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:61)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.dotmarketing.cms.urlmap.filters.URLMapFilter.doFilter(URLMapFilter.java:313)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.dotmarketing.filters.CharsetEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharsetEncodingFilter.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:465)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:555)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Caused by: org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Encountered "  "01/01/2012 "" at line 1, column 245.
Was expecting:
    "]" ...

```
at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.generateParseException(QueryParser.java:1759)
at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.jj_consume_token(QueryParser.java:1641)
at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Term(QueryParser.java:1399)
at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:1250)
at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:1207)
at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:1167)
at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:182)
... 41 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the ISO format for dates, e.g. `[2003-01-01 TO 2012-01-01]`.

Check out [this page](http://mike.hostetlerhome.com/2009/09/25/formatting-date-in-lucene-queries/). May also be related to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644500/searching-on-date-ranges-with-lucene-in-java).